# Как вернуть все объекты класса?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Нужно, чтобы класс мог вернуть все созданные объект этого класса. Можно статическим методом или обычным.

Допустим, есть класс:

```
class A ():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def GetAllObject(self):
        #Код, который вернет все объекты
        return list_object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из способов - добавлять self в статический список класса, однако для сборщика мусора нужно не забыть использовать weakref:

```
import weakref


class A:
    instance_list = list()

    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.instance_list.append(weakref.proxy(self))

    def GetAllObjects(self):
        return A.instance_list


obj1 = A()
obj2 = A()

print(A.instance_list)
# [<__main__.A object at 0x000002085E8793C8>, <__main__.A object at 0x000002085E8790B8>]
print(obj1.GetAllObjects())
# [<__main__.A object at 0x000002085E8793C8>, <__main__.A object at 0x000002085E8790B8>]
```

У данного кода есть существенная проблема: этот список никогда не чистится автоматически, его нужно обновлять вручную, что является не самой тривиальной задачей.

---

Намного более медленный способ - пройтись по всем объектам сборщика мусора и найти объекты нужного типа:

```
import gc


def GetObjectsOfType(type):
    objects_list = list()
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if isinstance(obj, type):
            objects_list.append(obj)
    return objects_list


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


obj1 = A()
obj2 = A()

print(GetObjectsOfType(A))
```

Comment: Хмм и как я сам до этого не дошел. Спасибо

Comment: @user12712868 если ответ ответил на ваш вопрос - поставьте +1 и примите его ;)

Comment: Да сейчас. Просто я до этого не мог, а потом отошёл